# Binding `len = length xs` and then calculating `len` causes GHC to consume lots of RAM

Tags: list, haskell, ghc, ghci

I found a strange thing about GHCi and lists.

This command takes some time to execute and just returns the right answer.

```
ghci> length [1..10^8]
100000000
```

However, binding this to a variable and executing causes GHC to consume about 5 GiB of RAM without releasing until the GHCi session is over. Typing `:quit` after it consumes 3 GiB more before actually exiting.

```
ghci> len = length [1..10^8]
ghci> len
-- Consumes 5 GiB
100000000
ghci> :quit
-- Consumes 3 GiB
-- Exits
```

Is this normal? What is the difference between the commands?

GHC version is 8.2.2.

Comment: I can reproduce it. https://gist.github.com/max630/657566ff4fc0fd082bf12099d685a1d7  Debian Jessie x64, stack lts-9.21. To me looks like some runtime leak. Note that gc does not report big memory residency.

Comment: If you use "**let** len = length [1..10^8]" there is no leak. Might be related to that the assignment without let is a new feature of ghci.

Comment: @max630 oh, interesting, I hadn't even considered that and wrote `let` in all tests. Without `let`, this indeed runs out of memory in GHC-8.2.1 and 8.3. Bug or just obscure difference in the evaluation strategy? Would be very strange this this were intended.

Comment: Using GHC 8.2.2 I can reproduce the leak and I can confirm it isn't there via `let`.    It is probably unrelated, but I see omitting `let` and using `:show bindings` reveals an additional binding that isn't there otherwise, namely `$trModule :: GHC.Types.Module = _`.

Comment: Ghci version 7 won't even let me do that i.e. declare a variable without using `let` keyword

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Update:* The optimization performed by `-O0` is a little different than I first understood.  Also, added a note about filing a new Trac bug.

I can reproduce this in GHC 8.2.2.  Directly evaluating the expression (or using `let` to bind it to a variable and then evaluating it) both complete quickly:

```
Prelude> length [1..10^8]
10000000    -- pretty fast
Prelude> let len = length [1..10^8]
Prelude> len
10000000    -- pretty fast
Prelude>
```

However, using the `let`-free syntax:

```
Prelude> len = length [1..10^8]
Prelude> len
10000000
Prelude>
```

takes longer and allocates a lot of memory which isn't freed until the session ends.

Note that this is specific to GHCi and interactive mode -- in a real, compiled Haskell program, there would be no issue.  Compiling the following will run quickly and not consume excess memory:

```
len = length [1..10^8]
main = print len
```

To understand what's going on, you should understand that Haskell is capable of performing two potential optimizations of this code:

1. It can explicitly create a lazy list and start computing its length but determine that once the beginning of the list has been counted, those elements will not be needed again allowing them to be immediately garbage collected.
2. It can determine that no list needs to be created at all, and via a process known as "list fusion", create compiled code that counts directly from 1 up to 10^8 without trying to put those numbers in any kind of data structure.

When this code is compiled with optimizations (`-O1` or `-O2`), GHC will perform optimization #2.  The compiled version will run quickly in a small amount of constant memory (a couple of megabytes resident for the runtime).  If you run this with:

```
$ time ./Length +RTS -s
```

to collect statistics, you'll find that GHC is still allocating about 1.6 gigabytes of heap, but this is actually to store the individual `Integer` values as they are being incremented.  (Since values in Haskell are immutable, a new `Integer` must be allocated for every increment.)  If you force the type to be `Int`:

```
len = length [(1::Int)..10^8]
```

then the program will allocate only a few kilobytes of heap, and you can see that truly there's no list being allocated.

It turns out that when this code is compiled without optimizations (`-O0`), GHC only performs optimization #1 (as pointed out by @Carl), but it manages to do a really good job of it, so much so that even though the GHC statistics show lots of heap allocation, the program *still* runs quite quickly with a very small memory footprint.

However, when this code is compiled to byte-code in GHCi, not only is just optimization #1 used, but GHC doesn't do quite so good a job of garbage collecting the list.  A huge multi-gigabyte list is generated, and the beginning is garbage collected *nearly* as fast as it's being generated.  Memory use ends up being quite large, but at least it's relatively constant.

You can see this by turning on timing/memory stats:

```
> :set +s
> length [1..10^8]
100000000
(1.54 secs, 7,200,156,128 bytes)
>
```

This means that this code actually allocates a 7.2 gigabyte list; fortunately, it can be thrown away almost as fast as it's generated, so the memory in use by the GHCi process after this computation will still be reasonably modest.

You'll see that:

```
> let len = length [1..10^8]
> len
```

and:

```
> len = length [1..10^8]
> len
```

chew through exactly the same enormous amount of memory (about 7.2 gigs).

The difference is that, for some reason, the `let` version allows the list to be garbage collected as it's counted, and the non-`let` version doesn't.

In the end, this is almost certainly a GHCi bug.  It might be related to one of the existing space-leak bugs that have been reported (e.g., Trac [#12848](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/12848) or [#14336](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/14336)), or maybe it's a new one.  I decided to file it as [#14789](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/14789), so maybe someone will take a look at it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure list fusion doesn't happen at `-O0`. I seem to recall it being implemented in terms of rewrite rules, and those require `-O1` or higher.

Comment: Huh, you're right.  I was thrown off because the `-O0` version still runs in small, constant memory.  I've tried to update the answer.

Comment: (1) is not an optimization, it is just how the language works.

Comment: I wonder why it doesn't optimize `length [a..b]` to a subtraction and increment.... Not implemented yet?